# What type of movement is this?

Tags: single-word-requests

When animals and population instinctively move from one place to another and come back again , this type of movement is called?

Answer (score 2):

I think you are referring to  [migration](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/Migration);  for animals, especially birds,  the the back and forth movement is determined by nature on a seasonal basis. For humans being different factors come into play and we also  talk about  *circular migration*.

> - The seasonal movement of a complete population of animals from one area to another. Migration is usually a response to changes in temperature, food supply, or the amount of daylight, and is often undertaken for the purpose of breeding. Mammals, insects, fish, and birds all migrate. The precise mechanism of navigation during migration is not fully understood, although for birds it is believed that sharp eyesight, sensibility to the Earth's magnetic field, and the positions of the Sun and other stars may play a role.  (from TFD)

[Circular migration](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_migration):

> - or repeat migration is the temporary and usually repetitive movement of a migrant worker between home and host areas, typically for the purpose of employment. It represents an established pattern of population mobility, whether cross-country or rural-urban. (from Wikipedia).

Comment: jinx. I owe you a coke. ').

Comment: Wait. You owe me a coke. Or maybe no one does, cause you were supposed to call jinx??? :(

Answer (score 0):

Are you referring to [*migration*](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/migration)?

> The seasonal movement of a complete population of animals from one area to another. Migration is usually a response to changes in temperature, food supply, or the amount of daylight, and is often undertaken for the purpose of breeding. Mammals, insects, fish, and birds all migrate. The precise mechanism of navigation during migration is not fully understood, although for birds it is believed that sharp eyesight, sensibility to the Earth's magnetic field, and the positions of the Sun and other stars may play a role. -AHDEL

Comment: I owe you a coke..of course!!:))

Comment: @Josh61 - Yesss!